# Linking multiple Ids to one Ids that belongs to same user

Tags: database, data-modeling

I have a system in which I want to generate unique User Ids for each user coming in the system. If a user changes device a new Id is developed for that same user. So, in the system, they are two different users but actually, they are not. If I have an email for some users and not all, how can I link these two Ids together?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to answer this question because it's unclear what you're asking, but I'll try:)

There are some variants:

1. You know in advance your unique user identifier, i.e. email. New user should pass it to system during registration
2. You know in advance your unique user identifier, but new user can finish registration without passing this info
3. You don't know in advance this unique user identifier

**First case** is quite simple - you should your unique user id (email) instead of generated unique id. So you can match new user and old one by this unique identifier right during registration process. For example I try to link my social account during registration and get message that such email has been already used.

**Second case** is more difficult - you can add email field in your user table and add index on it. In this case you can run simple query to find not unique user. Or you can maintain separate match table which looks like (email, user_id). For example it can contain such rows:

```
|   email        | user_id|
+----------------+--------+
|user@example.com|   1    |  
|user@example.com|   2    |
|test@example.com|   3    |
| .............. | ...... |
```

In this table you can add rows when you get information about unique user identifier (email in our case). So with this table you have matching between you different generated users through user unique identifier (email in our case)

**Third case** is more complicated than first and second:) You can't create any matching table in advance because you don't know user unique identifier.